# Why this error appeared 'input string was not in a correct format' with datepicker tool?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to view the payments between two dates but i get this error always 'input string was not in a correct format'.
I tested the SQL statement in the SQL server and its working but in C# application its not working.

I tried every thing converting to datetime and datetime.parse and checked the previous posts in this website but also not working, this is the table design , stored procedure and C# code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Payments](
    [patient_no] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [payDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
-------------
create proc [GET_PAYMENTS]
@patient_no int,
@fromdate datetime,
@todate   datetime
as 
SELECT payments.patient_no as 'رقم الملف',
       patients.Patient_name as 'اسم المريض'
      ,[Amount] as 'المبلغ المدفوع'
      ,format(payDate,'yyyy/MM/dd','ar-SA') as 'تاريخ الدفع'
  FROM [Payments]
  inner join patients on patients.Patient_no = payments.patient_no
where (Payments.patient_no = @patient_no or @patient_no is null)
and   (Payments.payDate between '@fromdate' and  '@todate')
```

Then I created a class in C# include SQL connection string , sqladapters , all stored procedures and parameters :

```
public DataTable GET_PAYMENTS(int Patient_no, DateTime fromdate, 
DateTime todate)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Patient_no", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[0].Value = Patient_no;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@fromdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[1].Value = fromdate;

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@todate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[2].Value = todate;

            dt = DAL.SelectData("GET_PAYMENTS", param);
            DAL.close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Last step in view payment window i select the date ranges by using 2 datetimepicker and select the patient file number, then when press the button I want to view the payments into DataGridView but I get this error, This is the button code :

```
private void BtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          BL.CLS_PATIENTS view = new BL.CLS_PATIENTS();
            dgvpayments.DataSource = view.GET_PAYMENTS(Convert.ToInt32(txtPno.Text), DateTime.Parse(fromdate.Text),DateTime.Parse(todate.Text));
        }
```

Comment: yourDateTimePicker.Value will return a DateTime you can use directly without needing to mess about with strings, currently the string format is presumably not directly parsable.

Comment: @Alex what is your suggestion and what i will change in the code?

Comment: Also don't quote your  '@fromdate' variables in the t-sql

Comment: change DateTime.Parse(xx.Text) to just xx.value

Comment: I removed the quote '@fromdate' & '@todate' and changed datetime.parse to fromdate.value & todate.value but still get same error.

Comment: You definitely need to remove quotes here `'@fromdate' and  '@todate'`. And your error probably comes from here  `DateTime.Parse(fromdate.Text)` or here `DateTime.Parse(todate.Text)`, or both. Try do this `var f = DateTime.Parse(fromdate.Text); var t = DateTime.Parse(todate.Text)`;  and then pass `f and t` to a method call. You will see that it throws error there, before the call. And it has something to do with culture. What is culture in your picker? What is it BTS winforms, ASP? WPF?

Comment: @T.S : i am using Hijri date and Arabic language culture

Comment: If you have not tried what I've recommended to you and not reported the result, then I am just wasting my time. See if this helps `DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`

Comment: @T.S: Sorry but my father died that night when i am trying your code may allah bless him. I will try your recommended and inform you

Comment: Sorry about your father. Let me know when you feel better.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the date thing which was already mentioned, I see something else.

In the procedure, you are allowing nulls to patientid, but in your application, you are explicitly not allowing nulls (indirectly).  If the textbox for patient number is blank, it'll bomb.

If you want to support nulls in the patient number, you'll need changes.

Here's a helper function, to be placed in the UI for simplicity, but could be elsewhere but will change the call definition below:

```
public static int? ToNullableInt(this string s)
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
    return null;
}
```

Here's the call change on the UI:

```
dgvpayments.DataSource = view.GET_PAYMENTS(ToNullableInt(txtPno.Text), DateTime.Parse(fromdate.Text),DateTime.Parse(todate.Text));
```

and the calling of the proc

```
public DataTable GET_PAYMENTS(int? Patient_no, DateTime fromdate, 
DateTime todate)
{
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Patient_no", SqlDbType.Int);
        if ( Patient_no.HasValue )
            param[0].Value = Patient_no;
        else
            param[0].Value = DbNull.Value;

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@fromdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[1].Value = fromdate;

        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@todate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[2].Value = todate;

        dt = DAL.SelectData("GET_PAYMENTS", param);
        DAL.close();
        return dt;
    }
```

I also recommend changes on the UI for validation:

```
    private void BtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DateTime fromDate;
      DateTime toDate;
      int patientNumber; 

      if (!DateTime.TryParse(fromdate.Text,fromDate))
      {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid From Date");
      }
      else if (!DateTime.TryParse(todate.Text,toDate))
      {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid to Date");
      }
      else if (txtPno.Text.Length >= 0 && !Int32.TryParse(txtPno.Text,patientNumber))
      {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid Patient Number");
      }
      else
      {
        BL.CLS_PATIENTS view = new BL.CLS_PATIENTS();
        dgvpayments.DataSource = view.GET_PAYMENTS(ToNullableInt(txtPno.Text), fromDate, toDate);
      }


    }
```

Comment: I add the details you mentioned but when i add the public static int? ToNullableInt(this string s) i get the error on my form                              public partial class VIEW_PAYMENTS : Form (extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class what is the reason ? and what to change